Workaround for function type invariance in heterogeneous list
I have the following Dart code
void main() {
  final filters = [
    FilterOption(
      label: 'Category',
      hint: 'All categories',
      items: A.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toUpperCase()
    ),
    FilterOption(
      label: 'Time',
      hint: 'All time',
      items: B.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toLowerCase()
    )
  ];
  try {
    filters.first.itemLabeler;
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print('Program terminated');
}

enum A {
  
  here, are, some, options
  
}

enum B {
  
  here, are, another, few, options
  
}

class FilterOption<T> {

  final String label;

  final String hint;

  final List<T> items;

  final void Function(T item) onChange;

  final String Function(T item) itemLabeler;

  const FilterOption({
    required this.label,
    required this.hint,
    required this.items,
    required this.onChange,
    required this.itemLabeler
  });

}

This is the output on DartPad
TypeError: Instance of '(A) => String': type '(A) => String' is not a subtype of type '(_Enum) => String'
Program terminated

I am aware of similar questions on StackOverflow, however, many either don't have answers to the problem or suggest implementation outside of a list. I would like to be able to send any number of FilterOptions to some UI element to display. I would also like the generic type to be any data type, not just enums. How can I solve this problem? Thank you to anyone who can offer any insight or solution.

One way to resolve the type error would be to force the list elements to the common base type: final filters = <FilterOption<Enum>>[...].  Doing so, however, will lose some type-safety since it would not prevent a String Function(B) from being passed where a String Function(A) is expected.

Thank you for the suggestion! I just tried it on DartPad and it eliminates the TypeError I've been dealing with entirely. I'll keep this in mind in case I deal with a similar issue in the future. I'll be designing an implementation based off of @mmcdon20 answer as it fits best with the problem I'm addressing presently but I appreciate the assistance nonetheless

Assuming filters are not just on enums, and don't have a common supertype, there are a few things you can try.
First, you can try to cast the FilterOption before using it.
void main() {
  final filters = [
    FilterOption(
      label: 'Category',
      hint: 'All categories',
      items: A.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toUpperCase(),
    ),
    FilterOption(
      label: 'Time',
      hint: 'All time',
      items: B.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toLowerCase(),
    ),
  ];
  try {
    (filters.first as FilterOption<A>).itemLabeler;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print('Program terminated');
}

enum A { here, are, some, options }

enum B { here, are, another, few, options }

class FilterOption<T> {

  final String label;

  final String hint;

  final List<T> items;

  final void Function(T item) onChange;

  final String Function(T item) itemLabeler;

  const FilterOption({
    required this.label,
    required this.hint,
    required this.items,
    required this.onChange,
    required this.itemLabeler
  });

}

Second, you can promote by testing with is or pattern matching with case before using.
void main() {
  final filters = [
    FilterOption(
      label: 'Category',
      hint: 'All categories',
      items: A.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toUpperCase(),
    ),
    FilterOption(
      label: 'Time',
      hint: 'All time',
      items: B.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toLowerCase(),
    ),
  ];
  try {
    // copy to local variable then check with is
    var first = filters.first;
    if (first is FilterOption<A>) {
      first.itemLabeler;
    }
    // check with pattern match
    if (filters.last case FilterOption<B> last) {
      last.itemLabeler;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print('Program terminated');
}

enum A { here, are, some, options }

enum B { here, are, another, few, options }

class FilterOption<T> {
  final String label;

  final String hint;

  final List<T> items;

  final void Function(T item) onChange;

  final String Function(T item) itemLabeler;

  const FilterOption({
    required this.label,
    required this.hint,
    required this.items,
    required this.onChange,
    required this.itemLabeler,
  });
}

Third, if you have a limited number of types you want to use, say Enum, String, and int, you could maybe get away with FilterOption a sealed class. This would allow you to exhaustively cover all options when switching over the data.
void main() {
  List<FilterOption> filters = [
    FilterOptionEnum(
      label: 'Category',
      hint: 'All categories',
      items: A.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toUpperCase(),
    ),
    FilterOptionEnum(
      label: 'Time',
      hint: 'All time',
      items: B.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toLowerCase(),
    ),
    FilterOptionString(
      label: 'String',
      hint: 'All string',
      items: ['hello', 'world'],
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toLowerCase(),
    ),
  ];
  try {
    switch (filters.first) {
      case FilterOptionEnum<A> a:
        a.itemLabeler;
      case FilterOptionEnum<B> b:
        b.itemLabeler;
      case FilterOptionEnum e:
        e.itemLabeler;
      case FilterOptionInt i:
        i.itemLabeler;
      case FilterOptionString s:
        s.itemLabeler;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print('Program terminated');
}

enum A { here, are, some, options }

enum B { here, are, another, few, options }

sealed class FilterOption<T> {
  final String label;

  final String hint;

  final List<T> items;

  final void Function(T item) onChange;

  final String Function(T item) itemLabeler;

  const FilterOption({
    required this.label,
    required this.hint,
    required this.items,
    required this.onChange,
    required this.itemLabeler,
  });
}

class FilterOptionEnum<T extends Enum> extends FilterOption<T> {
  FilterOptionEnum({
    required super.label,
    required super.hint,
    required super.items,
    required super.onChange,
    required super.itemLabeler,
  });
}

class FilterOptionInt extends FilterOption<int> {
  FilterOptionInt({
    required super.label,
    required super.hint,
    required super.items,
    required super.onChange,
    required super.itemLabeler,
  });
}

class FilterOptionString extends FilterOption<String> {
  FilterOptionString({
    required super.label,
    required super.hint,
    required super.items,
    required super.onChange,
    required super.itemLabeler,
  });
}

Fourth, you can try to wrap the callback functions in method calls:
void main() {
  final filters = [
    FilterOption(
      label: 'Category',
      hint: 'All categories',
      items: A.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toUpperCase(),
    ),
    FilterOption(
      label: 'Time',
      hint: 'All time',
      items: B.values,
      onChange: (_) => print('Not implemented yet'),
      itemLabeler: (item) => item.toString().toLowerCase(),
    ),
  ];
  try {
    filters.first.itemLabeler;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print('Program terminated');
}

enum A { here, are, some, options }

enum B { here, are, another, few, options }

class FilterOption<T> {
  final String label;

  final String hint;

  final List<T> items;

  final void Function(T item) _onChange;

  final String Function(T item) _itemLabeler;

  void onChange(T item) => _onChange(item);
  String itemLabeler(T item) => _itemLabeler(item);

  const FilterOption({
    required this.label,
    required this.hint,
    required this.items,
    required void Function(T item) onChange,
    required String Function(T item) itemLabeler,
  })  : _onChange = onChange,
        _itemLabeler = itemLabeler;
}



Thank you very much! I'll refactor my code to model this approach. If I may, do you happen to know if this is bad practice? I feel as though I'm trying to fight the language and I have also seen that function types are invariant by design. Perhaps my approach with this data type is not the optimal solution.

Hard to recommend exactly without knowing more about the problem, ideally you want homogeneous collections if possible, but I can give you some more options to work with.

See edited answer above.

Thank you. I might go with the sealed class method. Essentially, I'm trying to build a UI that displays a bunch of dropdown button filters regardless of data type. The callbacks are for when a value is chosen (the onChange callback) and to convert an option into text (the itemLabeler callback) for display in the dropdown. I initially thought the generics would create a ton of flexibility but the callbacks create lots of issues for me. This certainly wouldn't be a problem if all of the filters are of the same type but they won't be. That's where the heterogeneous list comes in.
